# Calculating the distance between two location coordinates fetching from SQL server

Tags: php, android, sql-server

I am creating an android application where it should fetch the data from sql table. In my sql table I have latitude and longitude coordinates stored in it. And i am able to pass current location co ordinates from my application to PHP code. And now I want to fetch the records where the distance between current location coordinates and stored co-ordinates must be **<= 50 kilometers**. How can I do it.

I have used `GET` method to fetch the current position from android application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you should do what you can to have SQL do the work for you. That way you minimize the number of results being returned to PHP.

What you're looking for is the [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

To accomplish the lookup in SQL you'll want to pass the two latitude and longitude points into the SQL query.  Here is an example of the SQL needed to do a distance lookup in Kilometers:

```
DECLARE @MyLat DECIMAL(18,6) = 50.066388;
DECLARE @MyLong DECIMAL(18,6) = -5.714722;

DECLARE @PointLat DECIMAL(18,6) = 58.643888;
DECLARE @PointLong DECIMAL(18,6) = -3.069999;

SELECT 6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(@MyLat))
    * COS(RADIANS(@PointLat))
    * COS(RADIANS(@MyLong) - RADIANS(@PointLong))
    + SIN(RADIANS(@MyLat))
    * SIN(RADIANS(@PointLat))) AS [DISTANCE_KM];
```

So you could delimit your database query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM LOOKUPTABLE
WHERE (6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(@MyLat))
    * COS(RADIANS(PointLat))
    * COS(RADIANS(@MyLong) - RADIANS(PointLong))
    + SIN(RADIANS(@MyLat))
    * SIN(RADIANS(PointLat)))) <= 50
```

Edit: As long as you're running SQL Server 2008 or later you could also use the geography Data Type to accomplish this. In this way you're getting more accurate geography based results:

```
DECLARE @MyLoc geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(50.066388 -5.714722)', 4326);
DECLARE @MapLoc geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(58.643888 -3.069999)', 4326);

SELECT @MyLoc.STDistance(@MapLoc)/1000;
```